# What happens when the Visual C++ compiler encounters AVX instructions while the "Enhanced Instruction Set" flag is disabled?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, simd, avx

In Visual Studio 2013, there is a flag located in the project `Configuration Properties > C/C++ > Code Generation` page called `Enable Enhanced Instruction Set`. It can be set to `SSE`, `SSE2`, `AVX`, `AVX2` or `IA32`.

`IA32` is specified as making "No Enhanced Instructions".

If I compile and run a project that uses `AVX` instructions, while having the flag set as `IA32`, it still works. Running the program also works fine.

What does the compiler do on this scenario ? Does it keep `AVX` instructions as they are because they are "hardcoded" and not compiler-generated instructions ? Or does the compiler replace these `AVX` SIMD instructions with SISD instructions ?

Comment: The flag controls what instruction set the compiler uses for code generation. (E.g., autovectorization.) But if you use them explicitly, well, that wasn't compiler-generated, so the flag does not apply. (But don't trust me on this. You can test it yourself. Look at the resulting compiler output to see whether the AVX instructions are translated to non-AVX instructions.)

Comment: That makes sense ! Sadly I don't see SIMD instructions in debug assembly builds and am not sure how to check release assembly generated by VS2013. What you say is consistent with what I see and seems logical given the location of the parameter on the "Code Generation" page. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's worth considering that the old x87 FPU ops aren't valid within an x64 binary, so if you have 64bit output enabled, setting IA-32 will be ignored, and SSE2 will be used as the default. If you happen to use AVX2 intrinsics within an app compiled for AVX (or prior instruction set), the AVX2 instructions will still be emitted within the binary, which will cause an app to hard crash on a CPU that doesn't support AVX2. See for example this:

https://godbolt.org/z/6VZhp-

Even though we are asking for x87, f() gets compiled using SSE2 (hence movss v.s. fld), and g() gets compiled using AVX2 instructions (e.g. vmovss).

So in  effect, Visual Studio allows you to insert AVX2 instrinsics into an SSE binary, but you will have to do your own cpuid checks to make sure the CPU supports those features before running that code.

Comment: "`if you have 64bit output enabled, setting IA-32 will be ignored, and SSE2 will be used as the default`" Do all 64 bit CPU support SSE2 instructions ? That would make sense with the default setting in Visual Studio when generating a 64bit program but I didn't realize it.

Comment: Yes, SSE2 is supported on all x64 cpus. It's a requirement for 64bit.

Comment: Intel's 64-Bit Extension Technology Software Developer’s Guide, Volume 1 of 2, P.2-176 is an example of x87 opcode in x64 mode. What is your reference for "...the old x87 FPU ops aren't valid within an x64 binary"?